# how to automatically set a superuser on creation a user type

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am using making use of some user_types in my application which are is_admin and is_landlord. I want it that whenever a user is created using the `python manage.py createsuperuser`. he is automatically assigned is_admin.

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_active=True,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            last_login=now,
            date_joined=now,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # CUSTOM USER FIELDS
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    telephone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
        
    def get_email(self):
        return self.email

class user_type(models.Model):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_landlord = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.is_landlord == True:
            return User.get_email(self.user) + " - is_landlord"
        else:
            return User.get_email(self.user) + " - is_admin"
```

**Note**: I want a superuser created to automatically have the is_admin status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automatically construct a `user_type` model in the `create_superuser` function:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    
    # …
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        user_type.objects.update_or_create(
            user=user,
            defaults={
                'is_admin': True
            }
        )
        return user
```

It is however not clear to my why you use a `user_type` class, and not just add extra fields to your `User` model. This will make it more efficient since these will be fetched in the *same* query when you fetc the logged in user. It is also more convenient to just access an `.is_landlord` attribute from the user model.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`user_type`</s> to `UserType`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I noticed that you used ```user_type..objects```.

Is that correct or it should be ```user_type.objects``` with just one period

Comment: @coderboy: thanks that was indeed a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

So I have tried a method that works not so efficiently but manageably.

What I do is a simple trick.

views.py

```
def Dashboard(request, pk):
    
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.pk)
        landlord = user.is_staff & user.is_active
        if not landlord:
            reservations = Tables.objects.all()
            available_ = Tables.objects.filter(status="available")
            unavailable_ = Tables.objects.filter(status="unavailable")
            bar_owners_ = user_type.objects.filter(is_landlord=True)
            context = {"reservations":reservations, "available_":available_, "unavailable_":unavailable_, "bar_owners_":bar_owners_}
            return render(request, "dashboard/super/admin/dashboard.html", context)
        else:
            """Admin dashboard view."""
            user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
            reservations = Tables.objects.filter(bar__user_id=user.id)
            available =Tables.objects.filter(bar__user_id=user.id, status="available")
            unavailable =Tables.objects.filter(bar__user_id=user.id, status="unavailable")

            context = {"reservations":reservations, "available":available, "unavailable":unavailable}

            return render(request, "dashboard/super/landlord/dashboard.html", context)
```

So I let Django know that if a user is active or has the is_active set to true only then they should have access to the dashboard else they wouldn't have access to it.